# Bash judgement gets the unexpected result

Tags: bash, if-statement

This is the code of the my shell script:

```
#! /bin/bash

if ["$SHELL" = "/bin/bash"];then
        echo "this is bash"
elif ["$SHELL" = "aa"];then
        echo "this is aa"
else
        echo "this is not /bin/bash, but $SHELL"
fi
```

why I execute the test_bash_03 script file gets the `else` result? shouldn't it be:`this is bash` ？

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:bash_demo ldl$ ./test_bash_03
./test_bash_03: line 3: [/bin/bash: No such file or directory
./test_bash_03: line 5: [/bin/bash: No such file or directory
this is not /bin/bash, but /bin/bash
```

And I echo the `$SHELL` I also get the `/bin/bash`

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:bash_demo ldl$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Note those errors? It's because of them. Add space before and after your `[` and `]`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I get that, thanks .

Comment: you can also use http://www.shellcheck.net/ to catch such typos and get other probable issues with script

Comment: @Sundeep Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that `$SHELL` does *not* contain the name of the currently running shell; it contains the name of the user's "preferred" shell (which is usually interpreted to mean the user's default login shell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a space after `[` and before `]`.

The bash tries to execute a command named `[/bin/bash` instead of `[` (which is `test`), then doesn't find that and has an exit code of 1 (false).  So you end up in the `else` case.